# Code to change color of button when the cursor hovers over it

Tags: html

I am creating an email template with a button. I would like the button to change colors when a user hovers over it.

The following is the HTML code I have for the button.

```
<div>
<!--[if mso]>
      <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="{!User.Calendly_Link__c}" style="height:32px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;" arcsize="13%" strokecolor="#1e3650" fillcolor="#ffffff">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#38383A;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Schedule a meeting</center>
      </v:roundrect>
    <![endif]--><a href="{!User.Calendly_Link__c}"
  style="background-color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid #FFC107;
  border-radius:4px;
  color:#38383A;
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height:32px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  width:150px;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
  mso-hide:all;"
  >Schedule a meeting</a>
</div>
```

Comment: There are many tutorials or other questions that address your problem on StackOverflow. Why weren't those satisfying ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simple example you can refer to:

### HTML

```
<button type='button' class='btn' > Submit </button>
```

### CSS

```
.btn {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, Angela! You can use `:hover` in CSS to create an effect when the user hovers over the element. Like this:

```css
button:hover {
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 350ms all;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```